# Custom Ecwid App not appearing at the checkout page

Tags: javascript

I am new to the Ecwid platform and I am building a custom courier app for dropshipping. I am using the Ecwid SDK JS file of version 1.2.8 `https://djqizrxa6f10j.cloudfront.net/ecwid-sdk/js/1.2.8/ecwid-app.js`. The issue now is, when I get to the storefront checkout page, as indicated by Ecwid developers API documentation, there should be a callback sent to my URL, in which I am not getting.

```
EcwidApp.init({
    app_id: "app_id",
    autoloadedflag: true,
    autoheight: true
});

EcwidApp.ready();

window.localStorage.setItem("show_ec_logs", "true");

let storeData = EcwidApp.getPayload();
let storeId = storeData.store_id;
let accessToken = storeData.access_token;
let language = storeData.lang;
let viewMode = storeData.view_mode;

if (storeData.app_state !== undefined) {
    var appState = storeData.app_state;
}

const initialConfig = {
    private: {
        merchantId: "app_id",
        APIsecret: "app_secret_token",
        endpointUrl: "https://ecwid-droppa-shipping.herokuapp.com",
        instructionTitle: "Droppa Instruction Title",
        globalShippingRate: "true",
        freeShippingRate: "true",
        installed: "yes"
    },
    profile: this.storeProfileInformation(storeId, accessToken)
};

EcwidApp.setAppStorage(initialConfig.profile, function (value) {
    console.log('Private User Preferences Saved:', value);
});

EcwidApp.getAppStorage('installed', function (value) {
    console.log(`Installed Application: ${value}`);
});

/**
 * @description - Display the Ecwid User's Store's information
 * @param {*} store_id 
 * @param {*} private_token ?
 * @returns 
 */
async function storeProfileInformation(store_id, private_token) {
    return await fetch(`https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/${store_id}/profile?token=${private_token}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzi'
        },
        mode: 'cors',
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((response) => response)
        .catch((errors) => console.log(errors));
}
```

Is there a way to get the app to appear at the checkout page? And I have all the scopes loaded on my app in the Ecwid dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is Harvel from Ecwid API team.

> *I am new to the Ecwid platform and I am building a custom courier app
> for dropshipping. Is there a way to get the app to appear at the
> checkout page?*

The code you sent is the code for the Merchant App settings, it loads in the Ecwid Admin.

In order to develop a custom courier app and display its shipping rates at the checkout page, you should have your own server that will receive requests from Ecwid, send requests to the 3rd party service and then back to Ecwid.
Once Ecwid receives the shipping rates from your app, these shipping rates will be visible at the checkout page and customers will be able to choose them.

**So, step-by-step and how it will work:**

1. Develop your own server; Ecwid sends data to your server (shipping
   URL);
2. Your server processes data and sends it to the 3rd party
   service;
3. 3rd party services sends shipping rates back to your
   server;
4. Your server sends shipping rates to Ecwid (they will be
   visible at the checkout page).

Shipping request example - https://api-docs.ecwid.com/reference/add-shipping-method#request-details.

Response with shipping rates example - https://api-docs.ecwid.com/reference/add-shipping-method#respond-with-shipping-rates.

Comment: Hey @Harvel, thanks for the response. Now I am using Heroku for hosting my application [link](https://ecwid-droppa-shipping.herokuapp.com/). Now when I use the Eciwd js file and adding my storeId to it, every time I go to my storefront, I always get a 404 status code. Is the issue now Heroku not throwing a success 200 status or maybe there another issue?! Or should I switch my hosting servers.

Comment: I'd like to sum up our email conversation here, in case anyone else needs this information. The 404 error issue has been resolved by creating a new server. Thus, if you ever face this error, feel free to contact us, yet kindly check on your side as well. 
**Regarding developing a shipping application in Ecwid** 
When you develop your shipping method, you should have 2 files: Merchant Settings (iframe URL) and Server side of your app (Shipping URL).

Comment: These files should be uploaded to any hosting, so they'd be accessible by direct links. Send us the links and we will add them to your app from our side.

If you ever have any questions, feel free to reach out to us: apps@ecwid.com.